# Difference between element.each and .each(element) in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the difference between

```
$(element).each(function(){
});
```

And

```
$.each("element",function(){
});
```

Comment: there's a difference i know both alert different when we alert(this)

Comment: There **is** a public API, you know: http://api.jquery.com/each/ and http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: Why did you tag this with PHP?

Comment: Normally php developer knows answer of this type of questions so i thought i'll get more views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: Well Mohit and Jonathan both of your answers was helpful for me thanks, I don't understand which answer is better for tick

Answer (score 4):

There *is* a difference. Per the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

> The $.each() function is not the same as $(selector).each(), which is
>   used to iterate, exclusively, over a jQuery object. The $.each()
>   function can be used to iterate over any collection, whether it is a
>   map (JavaScript object) or an array. In the case of an array, the
>   callback is passed an array index and a corresponding array value each
>   time. (The value can also be accessed through the this keyword, but
>   Javascript will always wrap the this value as an Object even if it is
>   a simple string or number value.) The method returns its first
>   argument, the object that was iterated.

Comment: Well Mohit and Jonathan both of your answers was helpful for me thanks, I don't understand which answer is better for tick

Comment: Surely this one as the other is just two links, doesn't really answer the question! ;)